Unable to allocate 30.8 GiB for an array with shape (3415, 1211817) and data type object
I am trying to obtain using features_from_place(). I am using the following tags:
tags = {'aeroway':'aerodrome',
                'aeroway':'hangar',
                'aeroway':'helipad',
                'aeroway':'heliport',
                'aeroway':'terminal',
                'amenity':True,
                'building': True,
                'craft':True,
                'cuisine':True,
                'healthcare':True,
                'historic':True,
                'landuse':True,
                'leisure':True,
                'natural': 'beach',
                'natural':'cave_entrance',
                'natural':'hill',                
                'office':True,
                'public_transport':'platform',
                'public_transport':'station',
                'shop':True,
                'sport':True,
                'tourism':True,
                'addr:street':True,
                'addr:flats':True
                }

And the query is for Berlin:
{ "city": "Berlin","country": "Germany", }

After a while of running the code, I get the error
"Unable to allocate 30.8 GiB for an array with shape (3415, 1211817) and data type object"

I know that the return of the function is a geodataframe. So this dataframe is having 3415 rows and 1211817 columns.
It seems that is the number of columns that require to allocate this much memory. Is there any way to reduce the number of columns retrieved? I understand that the number of columns refer to additional tags linked to the feature but most of them are unnecesary and consuming a lot of memory?
Is there any workaround to reduce the memory requirement?
Reading about geopandas and geodataframes, I found that the memory allocation problem could be addresed by splitting the geodataframe when reading. However, here as the method is already given, it is not an option.
I also tried by creating two geodataframes by splitting the tags I want to get but then the geodataframes have different number of columns and it is not possible to merge them.

That is an insane number of columns. I can try to take a look in a couple days when I'm back at my computer. In the meantime try a smaller neighborhood in Berlin, or a more limited set of tags to try to identify what specific OSM feature is causing that size.

This is the sort of thing that a sparse array would be ideal for…
